# Can't get Parsec to run on Ubuntu 18.04, missing avcodec58

Tags: apt, deb, libraries

i am currently trying to run Parsec on my Ubuntu 18.04 to connect to my remote Windows gaming rig.

it says which libraries are required.

As far as i can tell via synaptic is that the only dependend package missing is "libavcodec58 not found on your system. [-22]"

If i search in synaptic for "libavcodec58" i find a few libavcodec57 packages but none of them work.

Is there any other source where i can find a .deb file of this missing library?

Thank you guys in advance <3

Comment: When I do a Google search for the file you are looking for it is a .dll file. This is a windows only file. BTW You can not just use a .57 file when it needs .58. That would be like trying to use gas in a diesel engine. There appears to be a lot of detail missing in your question. Is this program a Ubuntu or Windows program? Please edit and add some detail.

Comment: The application is an ubuntu application. Newer versions of Ubuntu have libavcodec58, but 18.04 only has libavcodec57. When I search for libavcodec58 with synapticte and apt I can't find it.

Comment: Good chance then you need 20.04 or better still 22.04. Keep in mind 18.04 is EOL in a few months, so you would need to update soon.

Answer (score 0):

`libavcodec58` is available in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and 22.04 LTS, but is not available in older (e.g. 18.04) or newer (e.g. 22.10) versions of Ubuntu.

Consider using a Snap, Flatpak, or AppImage if available, as these formats work around these library dependency issues by bundling the needed library versions with the application.

If you really need it install `libavcodec58` on a version of Ubuntu that doesn't include it in the repositories, you could try manually downloading it (and any dependencies) [from here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libavcodec58), or if you need extra codecs download [this version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libavcodec-extra58&searchon=names).

In [my situation](https://github.com/Palakis/obs-ndi/issues/842), I needed to download and install a total of 5 packages.